# Выравнивание одной части текста в placeholder слева, а другой справа

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть поисковая строка на сайте, организованная через тег input. Как сделать так чтобы, например, текст "Найти..." был прижат к левой части, а лупа-эмодзи была прижата к правой части?

[image: Поисковая строка]

Comment: Так не получиться сделать, нужно чтобы лупа находилась в отдельном элементе, даже если вы будете использовать `::placeholder`, то будет изменяться весь текст, а не только какая-то буква, можно как бы криво через `transform` реализовать, но идея плохая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего никак, так как input не является контейнером. Можно поместить input в контейнер и уже там располагать декорации:

```css
.pseudo-input input,
.pseudo-input input:focus-visible {
  border-style: none;
  outline: none;
}

.pseudo-input {
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 3px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="pseudo-input"><input type="search" placeholder="Найти…"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь контейнер для инпута
Делаешь кастомный плейсхолдер

```css
.input-box {
  position: relative;
}

.custom-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-placeholder__icon {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

input::placeholder { 
  visibility: hidden;
}

.input-box:focus-within .custom-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .custom-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <input type="search" placeholder="...">
  <div class='custom-placeholder'>
    Найти...
    <span class='custom-placeholder__icon'>
      &#128269;
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPD:
Если нужно просто сделать иконку справа, а не кастомный placeholder, то можно ограничиться обёрткой над input-ом, и иконкой

Для иконки тогда убираешь `left: 0` и ставишь `right: 0`

Или просто добавить псевдоэлемент `::after` и стили к нему